# implicitly_wait doesn't work python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i got problem - click on button 'add to the bag' doesn't happen when using implicitly_wait. If i use time.sleep, all works ok, but time.sleep is bad method.
So, what i need? Get URl, click on device, click on 'add to the bag' button.
Yes, i know about https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html and https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/ but it not help for me. Please help me)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import time
try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get("https://www.oumua.me/shop")# Get URL
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]').click() #Click on device button
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]').click() #Click Add to the bag that doesn't working
```

Comment: just a note that all waits use time.sleep inside their polling loops.  There's nothing bad about time.sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe wait for it to be clickable?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]")))

element.click()
```

Comment: suddenly it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I can try to use javascript.

```
js = 'document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();'
driver.execute_script(js)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it works in browser console, but nothnig happend in python

Comment: I could try, with driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
It's other way

Answer (score 0):

I check and it's working for me without adding the `implicit` or `explicit` wait, in case you do not want to use `waits`, you can try the below way to click on this button

```
element = driver.findElement(By.CSS_SELECTOR(".styles__Button-sc-1fxagfa-17.styles__AddButton-sc-1fxagfa-18.bZGRJp.TZGpT"))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run it too, it doesn't work for me. It seems that somehow the `browser.page_source` does not have time to update. I think it's better to use explicit waits as @data_sc did.

P.S. Here it works, but it's not the best solution:

```
from time import sleep

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]').click()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]').click()
```